# Reduce redundant code with ImageViews and switch cases

Tags: java, android

I have 7 ImageView's having each a switch case of 7 different cases that have the same behavior of setting images for all 7 ImageView's. Is there any way to shorten the code for this, right now I have to call each ImageView's by its name in the switch case for all the ImageView's separately and it makes the code lengthy and amateur. Like the following switch code for all imageviews being called each with their imageview names.

```
 ImageView1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
 ImageView2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
 ImageView3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
 ImageView4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView4);
 ImageView5 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView5);
 ImageView6 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView6);
 ImageView7 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView7);

switch(x){
  case1:     
  ImageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image1));
  break;
  case2:
    ImageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image2));
  break;
  case3:
    ImageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image3));
  break;
  case4:
    ImageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image4));
  break;
  case5:
    ImageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image5));
  break;
  case6:
    ImageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image6));
  break;
  case7:
    ImageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Image7));
  break;
}
```

Comment: show the code, change names of variables if you're shy

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you could create an **Array of ImageView** and another one, with the **id's of the drawables**. Something like that:

```
int[] idOfDrawables= {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,...,R.drawable.image7};
ImageView[] bundleImageView= {ImageView1, ImageView2, ...,ImageView7};
```

After that you could create a method, where the logic will happen, like this:

```
public void setImageToImageView(ImageView[] bundleImageView, int[] idOfDrawables)
{
    for (int  i=0; i< bundleImageView.length; i++)
    {
        bundleImageView[i].setImageResource(idOfDrawables[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others suggested, create two arrays:

```
int[] ids = {R.drawable.Image1, R.drawable.Image2,...,R.drawable.Image7};
ImageView[] imageViews = {ImageView1, ImageView2, ...,ImageView7};
```

then use this:

```
private void showImage(int x, ImageView iv) {
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(ids[x - 1]));
}
```

if you want to put the image for `ImageView3` call `showImage(x, ImageView3)`

 or if you want to show the image for all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.length; i++) {
    showImage(x, imageViews[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your images as well as your imageViews in two separate arrays in a way that corresponds to each other, then use a for loop to loop through it.

```
findViewById...

int[] imageIds = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,...,R.drawable.image7};
ImageView[] imageViews = {image1, image2, ...,image7};

for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.length; i++) {
    imageViews[i].setImageResource(imageIds[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use butterknife open source project which helps you to decrease adding findviewbyId in your code.

Find the link for it

[Butterknife open source project](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)